# Wresting a simple dictionary from RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I am attempting to upgrade my current RestKit to 0.20.3, and in one case I need to get the result back as a dictionary, not mapped to any object.

Unfortunately, the code below results in an essentially empty RKMappingResult object, despite the fact that a correct dictionary does exist deeper in RestKit (I checked).

```
[self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]
                                       method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                  pathPattern:@"permission.json"
                                      keyPath:nil
                                  statusCodes:nil]];

[self loadObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]
          method:RKRequestMethodGET
            path:@"permission.json"
          params:nil
         success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *op, RKMappingResult *result) {
             if (success)
                 success([result dictionary]);
         }
         failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *op, NSError *error) {
             if (failure)
                 failure(error);
         }];
```

Load object calls the following:

```
RKObjectRequestOperation *const operation =
[self operationForObject:object
                  method:method
                    path:path
                  params:params
                 success:success
                 failure:failure];

[self.objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

return operation;
```

Can anyone give me some direction on how I might convince RestKit to give me back a dictionary?

Comment: what do you mean by deeper? Can you NSLog mappingResult?

Comment: can you return a value from `success`?

Comment: '"<RKMappingResult: 0xd239080, results={\n}>"' is the po of mappingResult.

Comment: By deeper, I mean, if I create a dynamic mapping and set the `ObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock`, a dictionary is passed in. That dictionary is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed one of the correct ways to create the mapping instance for a dictionary result:

```
[RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]
```

But you still need to set the key names that should be mapped or RestKit will just do no mapping.

Comment: So in order to get a dictionary result, I have to add all the keys of that dictionary to the mapping beforehand or RestKit just gives up? I just need the top-level JSON object represented as an NSDictionary, ie { "a" : "b" } -> @{ @"a" : @"b" }.

Comment: if you want all keys mapped, why use restkit? Why not just do a http call and convert the response to a nsdictionary

Comment: @ZayinKrige, it depends what other requirements you have, but in general you're correct - if you don't want any mapping, don't use RestKit.